# jQuery jsonp autocomplete invisible dropdown items

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The issue is that all the dropdown items are invisible. Autocomplete works, I get items, I can select them, the one in input changes on focus, cursor changes to pointer on hover over a item in dropdown. I think it is some css issue, but I haven't figured it in couple hours ...

Bellow is my ajax and autocomplete. Some comments: there is a data.shift() to remove first item (a variable that I need in the next step, it is not doing any harm). On select couple of hidden inputs will be filled, currently one is setuped and gets filled alright.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and the jquery:

```
$( "#id_city" ).autocomplete({
delay: 1000,
minLength: 0,
source: function( request, response ) {
$.ajaxSetup({ 
     beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
         function getCookie(name) {
             var cookieValue = null;
             if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                 var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                 for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                     var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                     // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                 if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                     cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
         return cookieValue;
         }
         if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
             // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
             xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
         }
     }
});
$.ajax({
url: '/country_auto/?country='+$("#id_country").val(),
dataType: "jsonp",
data: {
search:$('#id_city').val()
},
success: function( data ) {
data.shift();
response( data );
}
});
},
focus: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#id_city" ).val( ui.item.city );
return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#id_city" ).val( ui.item.city );
$('#id_latdeg').val(Number(ui.item.latdeg));
return false;
},
});
```

The JSON string looks like this:

```
([{"tz": "Europe/Bratislava", "city": "Handlova", "latmin": 43, "lon": "18E45",      
"latdeg": "48"}, {"tz":     "Europe/Bratislava", "city": "Hlohovec", "latmin": 25, 
"lon": "17E48", "latdeg": "48"}, {"tz":     "Europe/Bratislava", "city": "Humenne", 
"latmin": 56, "lon": "21E54", "latdeg": "48"}])
```

I think the setup is correct and it works. It is just the dropdown items are not visible ... they can be selected, everything is works, but they can not be seen ... Anybody has a idea how to fix this?

Comment: `I think it is some css issue` So why didn't you post relevant CSS and HTML markup in question???

Comment: Why you downvoting this? This is a implementation from jQuery manual, I don't have any custom css, it is only css imported from jQuery. Don't know what I should post ... I am not even sure what the element names are, because it is quite hard to catch them in Firebug .. they are handled by automcomplete function I have little control about this.

Comment: My bad then! You should provide online sample which replicates your issue

Comment: I my do that soon .. For now I still search for a solution and now I am quite sure this is not a css issue. It has something to do with jsonp. If I send a string like ['city1,latdeg,latmin,londeg ..etc'] it shows up fine. What I don't want is that all this data is visible in the dropdown, only city name should be there. So what I am looking for now is how to control the dropdown, how to choose what is showed there ...

Answer (score 2):

So, it works now as it should. The trick was that items in dropdown need to be named as label .. is probably somewhere written but it didn't come to me in nearly 16h I am working on this ... So, here is what works:

Server sends following string:

```
([{"tz": "Europe/Bratislava", "label": "Banovce nad Bebravou", "latdeg": "48",
 "lonmin":15, "londeg": "18", "latmin": 43}, {"tz": "Europe/Bratislava", "label": 
"Banska Bystrica", "latdeg": "48", "lonmin": 9, "londeg": "19", "latmin": 44}, {"tz": 
"Europe/Bratislava", "label": "Bardejov", "latdeg": "49", "lonmin": 16, "londeg": 
"21", "latmin": 17}, {"tz": "Europe/Bratislava", "label": "Bratislava", "latdeg": 
"48", "lonmin": 6, "londeg": "17", "latmin": 8}, {"tz": "Europe/Bratislava", "label":
"Brezno", "latdeg": "48", "lonmin": 38, "londeg": "19", "latmin": 48}])
```

So city is now called 'label'. That is most important to have. The changes to focus and select are like this:

```
success: function( data ) {
response (data);
}
});
},
focus: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#id_city" ).val( ui.item.label );
return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
$('#id_city').val(ui.item.label);
$('#id_latdeg').val(ui.item.latdeg);

return false;
},
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Autocomplete requires a very specific format for the items in the suggestion array. From the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

> **Array**: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:
>
> - An array of strings: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
> - An array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`
>
> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the label.
>
> **String**: When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is set to `"http://example.com"` and the user types foo, a GET request would be made to `http://example.com?term=foo`. **The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.**

Since your data does not match either of these requirements, you don't see any results (because the widget doesn't know how to display them).

There are two things you can do to fix this:

1. Provide some custom rendering and selecting logic so that the widget knows how to render the suggestions:

   To do this you'll need to implement a custom [`_renderItem`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) method and implement the `select` handler (and most likely `focus` as well, but the implementation is basically the same):

   ```
   $('#id_city').autocomplete({
       /* other options */
       select: function (event, ui) {
           /* Set the input's value to the item's "city" property */
           this.value = ui.item.city;

           // Prevent the default action, which is to place 
           // `item.value` in the field
           event.preventDefault();
       }
   }).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
       return $('<li />')
           .append($('<a />', { text: item.city }))
           .appendTo(ul);
   };
   ```

   **Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3xcLpaLw/
2. Transform your data into the format that the autocomplete widget expects.

   The canonical way to do this is to use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), transforming each item in your response object to a new object that autocomplete can handle:

   ```
   source: function (request, response) {
       /* your other code omitted for brevity */

       response($.map(data, function (item) {
           // for every item in your response array, add a "label" and "value"
           // property so that autocomplete can process the results.
           // in various event handlers, the "item" parameter will still have
           // the values you got from the server.
           item.label = item.city;
           item.value = item.city;

           return item;
       }));
   }
   ```

   **Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ys3jvkLh/1/

I've used the `city` property as an example, but really you could use any property on your response objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just posted my own solution in the same minute you posted this. From the look your seems to be the better approach, however I have been on this for hours, it works now, I don't want to touch it anymore :D Therefore I am not testing your solution and can not mark it as a answer. I don't have enough reputation to upvote you. Only thing I can say is thanks a lot for your time! Appreciate it, really.

Comment: @Stefan: No problem, if you decide to come back to it, hopefully it'll help :)